# What is the equivalent of the "tracert" DOS command?

Tags: networking, software-recommendation

tracert is a command in MS-DOS command prompt to trace the route to an IP Address.
Is there any command in the Gnome Terminal equivalent to this?

Comment: Just an aside: if you're referring to the command-line utility in Windows, it is just that, a Windows command-line application, not a MS-DOS application. MS-DOS has been out of favor for some 17 years (since the release of Windows 95) and certainly for a decade (since Windows XP came out, giving the NT kernel a huge boost in the home market).

Comment: hehe.. sorry. I generally use cmd, but for posting here i used that. btw thanks for the info :D

Answer (score 196, accepted):

Install the *traceroute* package via terminal by running:

```
sudo apt-get install traceroute
```

After that, type this in the terminal:

```
traceroute [ip/web-site domain]
```

For example:

```
traceroute 8.8.8.8
```

you can also use web-sites as well:

```
traceroute www.sitename.com
```

Comment: Have a look at `tracepath`, too.

Answer (score 95):

As an alternative to traceroute, you might use **mtr**, it's like traceroute on steroids.

**From the package description:**

*mtr combines the functionality of the 'traceroute' and 'ping' programs in a single network diagnostic tool.*

*As mtr starts, it investigates the network connection between the host mtr runs on and a user-specified destination host. After it determines the address of each network hop between the machines, it sends a sequence ICMP ECHO requests to each one to determine the quality of the link to each machine. As it does this, it prints running statistics about each machine.*

*mtr-tiny is compiled without support for X and conserves disk space.*

**To install it:**

```
sudo apt-get install mtr-tiny
```

**Usage example:**

```
mtr example.lan
```

**Example output:**

```
                             My traceroute  [v0.71]
            example.lan                           Sun Mar 25 00:07:50 2007

                                       Packets                Pings
Hostname                            %Loss  Rcv  Snt  Last Best  Avg  Worst
 1. example.lan                        0%   11   11     1    1    1      2
 2. ae-31-51.ebr1.Chicago1.Level3.n   19%    9   11     3    1    7     14
 3. ae-1.ebr2.Chicago1.Level3.net      0%   11   11     7    1    7     14
 4. ae-2.ebr2.Washington1.Level3.ne   19%    9   11    19   18   23     31
 5. ae-1.ebr1.Washington1.Level3.ne   28%    8   11    22   18   24     30
 6. ge-3-0-0-53.gar1.Washington1.Le    0%   11   11    18   18   20     36
 7. 63.210.29.230                      0%   10   10    19   19   19     19
 8. t-3-1.bas1.re2.yahoo.com           0%   10   10    19   18   32    106
 9. p25.www.re2.yahoo.com              0%   10   10    19   18   19     19
```

Answer (score 11):

`traceroute`, `traceroute6`, `tracepath` perform this task. They are executable programs installed in Unix systems (somewhere in `/usr/bin/`, or `/bin/`, or `/usr/sbin/`, or `/sbin/` -- the last two are not in the PATH for a normal user, only for root). They are independent of any terminal package.

Comment: do i need to install anything to use it?

Comment: @vipin8169 I'm not sure whether it is installed by default in Ubuntu. Will have to check the name of the package which it belongs to. Perhaps someone else can help and edit the answer? I'm not currently working on an Ubuntu system.

Comment: actually i installed traceroute package before trying tracepath, it worked.. but i don't know if it was related to that install or not

Comment: ...additional flags for `tracepath` may be found at this link http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/tracepath.8.html

Answer (score 4):

So, **tracepath** is most suitable option to your question if taking in account that you used as a reference a native software (tracert).

Something that worth to mention is that **tracepath** is in the standard installation package of Ubuntu. Hence, if you are a Ubuntu lover, you may consider learning it instead of **traceroute** or **mtr**.

**mtr**, in the other hand is widely used by collocation providers because additional features 
that may be very useful while tracking problems, while **traceroute** has a very suggestive name that is easy to remember.

Comment: tracepath is a good one for me because I'm running 20.04 and it's available without having to installing anything else.  thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe this has changed. You no longer type the traceroute command line with the "ip/website url" configuration. Instead you will need to type:

```
traceroute <websiteinquestion.com (org, net, gov, whatever)>
```

I don't know why this has been simplified but after attempting to find a solution as to why Hulu.com was freezing up on me it was suggested to try a `traceroute` command. On a hunch I tried it with just the domain name and extension and it worked perfectly.