# having problem browsing on ubuntu 15.04

Tags: wireless, 15.04

Just recently installed Ubuntu `15.04.` My Mi-fi would connect to my computer but wont browse please kindly assist me

Comment: check you have ip issued by the wireless router..

Comment: Confirm if you connecting to 'Mi-Fi' via WiFi (eg. wireless), which is in turn connected to Internet, or are connecting Mi-Fi to USB port.

Comment: Thanks i can connect to the mi-fi, but wont browse the net

Answer (score 2):

Its difficult to tell what's wrong by hearing this kind of statement.. 
 "My Mi-fi would connect to my computer but wont browse"
you have to troubleshoot step by step and use [process of elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_of_elimination)
Since you have already confirmed wireless is connected fine,check you have ip address issued by the wireless device/router first.. To check that open a terminal and type

```
sudo ifconfig
```

If ip is in the range of wifi device that is issued, then ip is ok. Yet you can't browse then check gateway is ok, .. Use terminal and type

```
sudo route
```

if that one also looks good, next it may be DNS issue, try to have a ping .

open a terminal and 
`ping 8.8.8.8`

and also

`ping www.google.com` ..

This will help you to eliminate dns are ok or not.. If 8.8.8.8 pings are someting similar `xx bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=xx ms`  and ping www.google.com gives you ping: `unknown host www.google.com` potentially there could be a dns issue..

If everything works fine, yet cant browse, then use [tracert kind of equivalent](https://askubuntu.com/questions/189713/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-tracert-dos-command) : to make sure upper level firewall or similar device is blocking/not blocking your path..

(and also if this is a business/working/enterprise environment they may use proxy settings etc )

If these things are too much technical for you , get in touch with your friend who is capable of helping you..

Comment: Thanks when i ping 8.8.8.8 and ping.google.com they worked, but still could not browse the web. unfortunately i dont have anyone to assist me

Comment: what would be the output of ping www.google.com? and can you browse this http://74.125.68.147/

Comment: henry@Polaris:~$ ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (64.15.112.123) 56(84) bytes of data.

Comment: yes i can browse 74.125.68.147, but not through my mi-fi wireless device